# How to create a class with a queue as a data member which stores instances of another class in c++

Tags: c++, class, include

I have a class `office` which is simulating a veterinarian office which of course processes animals.

I have another class `dog`, I wish to generate several instances of dogs into a queue inside of the office class to process the animals in first in first out order.

I understand how to use a queue when working with primitive data types, but I am confused on several matters when it comes to queues and adts.

In the office header file how do I implement the queue itself?  I am assuming it will go in the public section, where as the private section would be for information like the name of the clinic, its address, etc of the office.(please correct me if am wrong!)  However I don't believe I can just use `include <queue>` inside of a header file to allow queues to be used how can I get around this?

Comment: Do you want users of the class to modify the queue of animals at will? If so, make it public. Second, why wouldn't including the queue header allow you to use queues?

Comment: I was just unsure as whether or not you could include libraries in header files

Answer (score 3):

Based on your description, I'd start with something on this order:

```
#include <queue>

class office { 
    std::queue<dog> patients;
public:
    void enter(dog const &d) { patients.push(d); }

    void treat() { 
        dog patient = patients.front(); 
        patients.pop(); 
        do_treatment(patient); 
    }
};
```

Of course, the `dog` class has to be defined before this one is.

Comment: Ahh the scope resolution operator this makes sense now and yes dog has already been defined

Answer (score 0):

You want to use template programming, and build a 'templated' queue or vector object.

e.g.

```
#inlcude<vector>

class MyFancyClass; //define elsewhere
MyFancyClass ob1,ob2 ,obn; //instantiate objects
std::vector<MyFancyClass> container;

container.push_back(ob1);
container.push_back(ob2);
container.push_back(ob3);
```

Having said that, you want to store pointers to the object in a Queue or Vector instead of copying the object around.

Comment: A queue or vector of pointers to the dog object? and so i would have but one dog object initialized in the main function which would be referenced by many different pointers, referencing the dog objects information?